# Ubuntu 14.04.03 installer fails to recognize UP board's internal storage

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04.03 on my UP board which has 32GB of internal storage(eMMC) for a particular use. Unfortunately, installer fails to recognize UP's storage.

I had previously installed Ubuntu 16.04.03 on the same board without any error.

I also tried Ubuntu 14.04.03 live and it fails to recognize the internal storage either.

Has anyone had the same problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Boot into `memtest86+` to verify.

Comment: Try the newest, 14.04.5. If you try 16.04 again, does it work?

Comment: I have to install 14.04.03 for my special use.

Comment: Yes 16.04 works.